# get latest 5 posts and a specific post and sort in a specific order

Tags: loop

I'm looking for some advice on how to make a gallery of images.
it is a particular bit a gallery, because I would show the last 5 post and a fixed post, for a total of 6 posts, in a specific order. ie the fixed post must be the third in the list.
The only method that I believe it is possible to create 3 loops, the first to see the last two post, the second to display the fixed post (by id), and the third to see other last three posts.
Something like this (most probably it is not correct):

```
        <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' ); // get the latest 2 posts
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; 
        ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php $my_query2 = new WP_Query( 'p=1' ); // get fixed post with id=1
            while ( $my_query2->have_posts() ) : $my_query2->the_post();
        ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php $my_query3 = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); // get the latest 3 posts
            while ( $my_query3->have_posts() ) : $my_query3>the_post();
            if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; // don't show the same post of the first loop
        ?> 

            <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

There's a different way to do this without do many loops, considering that there's already one in the page ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a way of getting the latest 5 posts plus a specific one in a single query without using SQL.

If you don't mind using two queries, I think this would be an easy way to do what you intend:

```
//Get the latest 5 posts (which happens to be get_posts default 'posts_per_page' value)
$posts = get_posts();

//Build up an array with the IDs
$latests_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );

//Insert the desired ID in the third position
$post_id_to_insert = 1;
$insert_position = 2; //which equals 3 when starting from 0
array_splice( $latests_posts_ids, $insert_position, 0, $post_id_to_insert );

//Get the posts based on the IDs and do not alter their order
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post__in' => $latests_posts_ids,
    'orderby' => 'post__in'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

//Parse the posts
foreach( $posts as $post ) :

    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();

endforeach;
```

I'm using [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) but you can safely use [WP_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

WordPress already handles possible duplicates in `post__in`, which would be the case if the post you want to insert is one of the latest 5.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: your code doesn't work if there'r multiple loop on the same page. The second loop is like the first. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @sb0k, use `wp_reset_postdata()` between both.

Comment: i closed the first loop with endofeach; wp_reset_postdata(); & wp_reset_query();. but nothing...

Comment: What are your arguments for `get_posts()` on the second loop? As it's in my answer, it will retrieve the five latest posts. You might need to change its query parameters to achieve a different result.

Comment: both loop are in the blog page (home.php) , then i specifed only the first loop.

Comment: This is not related at all to your original question. I think the correct procedure here would be to mark this as solved (if this solution works as you intend for your first loop) and then ask a separate question with your updated code. This way things are kept apart: this question can be helpful for users in the future and you will get more support from other users in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the built in counter to tell how many times you've been through the loop, then use `get_post` on the fixed posts id once you've been through 3 times...

```
 <?php 
        $my_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); // get the latest 5 posts
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; 
    ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php 
         if(3 == $my_query->current_post) {
             $fixed_post = get_post(1);
             // Do what you need to with $fixed_post...
         }
         endwhile; 
    ?>
```

See the wordpress developer reference for [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) for more details...

(Editted code to use built in counter as per suggestion of Milo in comments.)

Comment: you can also use the counter built into every query object, `$my_query->current_post`

Comment: Even better. I'll update answer...

Comment: thank you so much.. is a solution which I had not thought. I'm sure that will give good results.